# jQuery expression not being unrecognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following html in my view

```
<div id="divLoginName" style="display: none">
        <input type="hidden" id="hidLoginName" />
        @Html.TextBox("txtEditLoginName", null, new { maxlength = "1000", tabindex = "0", Multiline = false, @style = "width: 350px;" })
    </div>
```

and the following jquery lines

```
  var loginName = $.trim($tr.find(".tdLoginName").html());
  $("#divLoginName input:[type='text']").val(loginName);
```

I'm getting below error at the this line `$("#divLoginName input:[type='text']").val(loginName);`

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #divLoginName input:[type='text']

Comment: It should simply be: `$("#divLoginName input[type='text']").val(loginName);` without the colon.

Comment: You could do `$("#divLoginName input:text")`

Answer (score 4):

Remove colon after `input`:

```
$("#divLoginName input[type='text']")
                     ^^^
                no colon there
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to get input text

```
$('input[type=text]');
```

The example you are looking for is this: ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/stmpwhyx/))

```
$('input[type=text][id=txtEditLoginName]').val()
```

To make clear, how you can get it properly:

```
$('div input[name][id][value]')
```

I hope it´s helps.

Comment: Technically correct, however there may be more inputs on the page than what the code snippet suggests